# how to enable podNodeSelector admission controller plugin in GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I know it is impossible install kubeadm in GKE.

Is it possible enable podNodeSelector admission controller plugin in GKE?

Comment: Have you checked if [`ValidatingAdmissionWebhook`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#prerequisites) is available in GKE? Then you could implement whatever logic you wanted

Comment: yes, ValidatingAdmissionWebooks is available on GKE. Dreamer, in order to help you build a admission controller that fits your needs, post an example rule you wan't to apply.